# How to read and write Data in Airtable with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, airtable

dependencies:
airtable: ^0.0.2
import 'package:airtable/airtable.dart'; ??

import 'package:dart_airtable/dart_airtable.dart'; ??

```
void main() async {
  final apiKey = 'my-airtable-api-key'
  final projectBase = 'my-airtable-project-base';
  final recordName = 'Tasks';

  var airtable = Airtable(apiKey: apiKey, projectBase: projectBase);
  var records = await airtable.getAllRecords(recordName);

  print(records);
}
```

If anyone knows how to solve it, I will be very grateful.

Comment: So what is the problems with the plugin? What issue do you encounter?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I dont know how to read an specific table into the base, or how to create a record in a specific table.
Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it seems like you mix two things together. Currently there are two `packages` that provide a library for the communication with airtable: [airtable 0.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/airtable) and [dart_airtable 0.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_airtable).

In your example code you use the import statement for the first `package` but the code from the second one. As the first one doesn't provide a valid link to a `repository` I'll have a look at the second one.

To retrieve `records` for a project from the API you can use this code:

```
var records = await airtable.getAllRecords(recordName);
```

Unfortunately the `package` has some bugs. As I wanted to create a record I used the method `createRecord` like this:

```
var test = await airtable.createRecord(
  recordName,
  AirtableRecord(
    fields: [
      AirtableRecordField(
        fieldName: 'Short Description',
        value: 'Test Description',
      ),
    ],
  ),
);

print(test);
```

But the only `response` I got was `null`. So I cloned the project and debugged the method. The result was this:

```
{"error":{"type":"INVALID_REQUEST_UNKNOWN","message":"Invalid request: parameter validation failed. Check your request data."}}
```

After a little bit of searching I found out that the `package` sends wrong data to the airtable API. In a `toJson` method of the `AirtableRecord` model, the author added the unnecessary fields `id` and `createdTime`. After deleting them, the method works.

Response:

```
AirtableRecord(id: rec9bqN78Le1dbC1g, createdTime: 2020-10-20 19:10:21.000Z, fields: {Short Description: Test Description})
```

**I didn't look for the remaining methods, but my advice is to write your own connection to the airtime API or use the existing `package` and change the things that aren't working. Hopefully this helps you.**

Edit:

I'll checked the `repository` again, and it seems that the author is inactive. As it only contains a few methods and models to work with the airtable API, I'll guess it's not a bad idea to just wrote your own implementation.

Here an simple example of how to do this (with [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for the network connection):

```
try {
  final response = await Dio().post(
    'https://api.airtable.com/v0/$projectBase/$recordName',
    options: Options(
      contentType: 'Application/json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourApiKey',
        'Accept': 'Application/json',
      },
    ),
    data: {
      'records': [
        {
          'fields': {
            'Short Description': 'Cactus',
            'Total': 11.5,
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  );

  // TODO: Whatever you want to do with the response. A good practice is to transform it into models and than work with them
  print(response);
} on DioError catch (e) {
  // TODO: Error handling
  if (e.response != null) {
    print(e.response.data);
  } else {
    print(e.request);
    print(e.message);
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{"records":[{"id":"recrvxH93gJgAGo7j","fields":{"Short Description":"Cactus","Total":11.5},"createdTime":"2020-10-21T20:41:19.000Z"}]}
```

You could now extend this, maybe as a `service` with the [`GetIt`](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) package and add your required funtions. I definetly recommend to also use `models` for your `response` (have a look at [this](https://app.quicktype.io/)).

I used one of their example workspaces. The projectBase was an ID. You can just look at their API documentation to see how to build the `requests`.

Edit 2:

Read could be simple done by this:

```
final response = await Dio().get(
    'https://api.airtable.com/v0/$projectBase/$recordName',
    options: Options(
      contentType: 'Application/json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourApiKey',
        'Accept': 'Application/json',
      },
    ),
  );
```

Update:

```
final response = await Dio().patch(
    'https://api.airtable.com/v0/$projectBase/$recordName',
    options: Options(
      contentType: 'Application/json',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourApiKey',
        'Accept': 'Application/json',
      },
    ),
    data: {
      'records': [
        {
          'id': 'rechYkD0pDW1NjFAF',
          'fields': {
            'Short Description': 'Cactus II',
            'Total': 11.5,
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  );
```

And delete:

```
final response = await Dio().delete(
    'https://api.airtable.com/v0/$projectBase/$recordName/rec0bMv507juqS7pv',
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourApiKey',
        'Accept': 'Application/json',
      },
    ),
  );
```

These are only examples, I advice you to also read the API documentation to get a overview of what is possible. And your own implementation with proper error handling.

Edit 3:

You can use the `filterByFormula` parameter to retrieve all the data that matches your condition ([Reference](https://community.airtable.com/t/how-to-search-for-specific-value-through-api-filterbyformula/21271/3)).

E.g.:

```
final response = await Dio().get(
    'https://api.airtable.com/v0/$projectBase/$recordName',
    queryParameters: {
      'filterByFormula': 'SEARCH("Cactus",{Short Description})' // Searches the value 'Cactus' in the 'Short description' field.
    },
    options: Options(
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $yourApiKey',
        'Accept': 'Application/json',
      },
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Matthias! Thanks you very much! Could you give me a full example about how I have to made the code, so I could copy and paste it. Because I don't understand how implement it. I keep getting null as result. 

The "createdTime" it could be very useful  for what I need to do. if you add it to the explanation it would be great.

Comment: Also I don´t understand what I have to write in projectBase, the name? the ID? and what about the Table? In each base there are many tables, how can I configure an specific Table?

Comment: Thanks you very much It worked perfectly!! I could add records but now, how can I read/update or delete an specfic record?

Comment: Thanks you very much! The last question and I don't bother you anymore.

I 'm making a "coupon system.  I need that when the user insert the string code" the system  read the data searching the code in a specific field named "codes" and then  read also the "date" field in the same row to check the vigency.

Basically, do you know how can I get the specific ID of the row only with a string data(the code) of a field.?

Comment: See Edit 3 for a short explanation.

Comment: Thanks you  Matthias!! You help me very much. The only thing I didn´t figure out is how to read an specific record in specific field its that possible? 
thanks to the last edit, now I can get the record id substracting letters, and I would like to get/read a specific record in a field.

Comment: Your welcome, I'm not sure what you are meaning. Can you give an example?

Comment: I could figure it out by my own. I finished the App thanks to you. I 'm extremely grateful!! Thanks!!